# Uncaught TypeError: database_ref1.child(...).remove(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am new to programming and I caught the above error.
But the function works well should I ignore it or are there any solutions.

```
function deleteUser() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
    user.delete().then(() => {
      // User deleted.
    }).catch((error) => {
      // An error occurred
      // ...
    });
    var database_ref1 = database.ref()
    database_ref1.child('users/' + user.uid).remove() ({
        
    }, (error) => {
        if (error) {
          // The write failed...
        } else {
          // Data saved successfully!
        }
    });
}
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: you should fix it ... you try to delete user by user.delete and redelete the same user that is not found it why you get .remove(...) is not a function

Comment: Right.  Do you see the point?  You call `user.delete()`, which is going to delete that user's record.  You then try to fetch that record, but it has already been deleted.

Comment: Use concole log to display database_ref1.child('users/' + user.uid) to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes should fix it... You get issue at this line :

```
database_ref1.child('users/' + user.uid).remove() // child(uid) return null
```

because you try to fetch the current user that has been already be delete by :

```
user.delete()
```

to delete **current user** just do :

```
function deleteUser() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    user.delete().then(() => {
        // User deleted.
    }).catch((error) => {
        // An error ocurred
        // ...
    });
}
```